# NERDTree seems to perform :lcd

Tags: plugin-nerdtree

Every time I open a file from NERDTree, it seems to do a `:lcd` to the location of that file. If I open 5 files from NERDTree, I will have 5 different working directories in each buffer. I can't seem to find the setting that affects this behavior.

Comment: er... `lcd` is [not used inside](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=lcd&type=) the NerdTree plugin that i can find.

Comment: I guessed as much, it does not seem to be a designed behavior. Probably it has nothing to do with NERDTree, but a Vim setting (which is why I had the 'default-setting' tag on). When opening a new buffer with `:e` it does not have the same behavior though.

Comment: NERDTree [checks an flag called `g:NERDTreeChDirMode`](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree/blob/f6987b7ea6e839055b400fbe4a6fab1d38e7a26a/lib/nerdtree/creator.vim#L59-L61) to see if it should [change the directory](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree/blob/183bb53485f32f3be5e920cedc657dfc9c6d7eda/lib/nerdtree/path.vim#L72-L84). Do you have that set?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that I did check `g:NERDTreeChDirMode`. It is not set.

Comment: Furthermore, NERDTree's `changeToDir` does a `:cd` and not a `:lcd`. It also [echos](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree/blob/f6987b7ea6e839055b400fbe4a6fab1d38e7a26a/lib/nerdtree/path.vim#L80) the new working directory, which I don't see. I think it's safe to say that this happens outside NERDTree. But which Vim setting could cause this?

Comment: So, I finally figured this one out. A big clue was that it was only doing it on certain file types, specifically markdown. It turns out that the pandoc plugin has an enabled-by-default module that changes the directory to the current file's location. I disabled it and voila.